# Integrate Sentry with Mojolicious

Tags: perl, sentry, mojolicious

Is there a solution that automatically sends Mojolicious' errors to Sentry? For Express, it's as easy as

```
Sentry.init({
    dsn: 'http://asdf@sentry.somwhere/2',
})

const app = express()

// The request handler must be the first middleware on the app
app.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are plugins to do that:

1. [`Mojolicious::Plugin::ErrorTracking::Sentry`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::ErrorTracking::Sentry);
2. [`Mojolicious::Plugin::ExceptionSentry`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::ExceptionSentry)